# How to compute $\int\sqrt{\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to find the following integral,

### $\int\sqrt{\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})}dx$

Thank you very much!

Comment: Plonk it into Wolfram Alpha. See what you get. Then post your results here.

Comment: It did not give a solution to this problem, I tried it with MATHEMATICA, it gave as follows, \[Integral]Sqrt[Log[1 + 1/x]] \[DifferentialD]x

Comment: Well, then it has _no closed form_! You're out of luck. You need numerical integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in comments, there no closed form expression for this antiderivative.

Let me suppose that you need it for the evaluation of $$I=\int_a^b \sqrt{\log \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}\, dx$$ where $a$ and $b$ are large numbers.

First, change variable $x=\frac 1y$, $dx=-\frac {dy} {y^2}$. This makes $$I=-\int_{\frac 1a}^{\frac 1b}\frac{\sqrt{\log (1+y)}}{y^2}\,dy$$ Now, let us use the Taylor expansion around $y=0$ $$\log(1+y) = \sum^\infty_{n=1} (-1)^{n+1}\frac{y^n}n \quad\text{ for } |y| < 1$$ Truncating to $O\left(y^{6}\right)$ $$\log(1+y) =y-\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{y^3}{3}-\frac{y^4}{4}+\frac{y^5}{5}+O\left(y^{6}\right)$$ Now, using the generalized binomial theorem, we then have $${\sqrt{\log (1+y)}}=\sqrt{y}-\frac{y^{3/2}}{4}+\frac{13 y^{5/2}}{96}-\frac{35 y^{7/2}}{384}+\frac{6271
   y^{9/2}}{92160}-\frac{2211 y^{11/2}}{40960}+O\left(y^{13/2}\right)$$ $$\frac{\sqrt{\log (1+y)}}{y^2}=\frac{1}{y^{3/2}}-\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{y}}+\frac{13 \sqrt{y}}{96}-\frac{35
   y^{3/2}}{384}+\frac{6271 y^{5/2}}{92160}-\frac{2211
   y^{7/2}}{40960}+O\left(y^{9/2}\right)$$ Integrating each term $$\int\frac{\sqrt{\log (1+y)}}{y^2}\,dy=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{y}}-\frac{\sqrt{y}}{2}+\frac{13 y^{3/2}}{144}-\frac{7
   y^{5/2}}{192}+\frac{6271 y^{7/2}}{322560}-\frac{737
   y^{9/2}}{61440}+O\left(y^{11/2}\right)$$ Now, apply the bounds.

For illustration purposes, let me use $a=1000$, $b=2000$. The above formula will give a value $\approx 26.192536692759871823$ while a numerical integration would give exactly the same digits.

Suppose that we develop $\log(1+y)$ up to $O\left(y^{p}\right)$. For the given example, the results would be 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p &  \text{integral} \\
 1 & 26.197165896624001216 \\
 2 & 26.192534848210658268 \\
 3 & 26.192536693708417188 \\
 4 & 26.192536692759311737 \\
 5 & 26.192536692759872186 \\
 6 & 26.192536692759871823 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thank you Claude, you are so smart

Comment: By the way, can you explain a bit how you used  the generalized binomial theorem

Comment: How did you use the generalized binomial theorem to \log(1+y) =y-\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{y^3}{3}-\frac{y^4}{4}+\frac{y^5}{5}+O\left(y^{6}\right)?

Comment: @DilrukGallage. I started with the Taylor series of $\log(1+y)$ and applied the generalized binomial theorem to $\sqrt{1+t}$ using later $t=y-\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{y^3}{3}-\frac{y^4}{4}+\cdots$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got the point